# what is Batch file (.bat) equivalent for if [-f $path ]

Tags: linux, shell, batch-file

how to convert the following into batch

```
if [ -f /images/$CMVC_RELEASE/latest ]; then
  rm -f /images/$CMVC_RELEASE/latest
fi
```

Comment: What do you mean by *batch*? A Windows `.bat` file?

Comment: `if exist "\images\%CMVC_RELEASE%\latest" del "\images\%CMVC_RELEASE%\latest"` would be a Windows batch code to delete file `latest` in folder according to value of environment variable `CMVC_RELEASE` in folder `images` which is a subfolder of root of current drive.